# Login to Home screen throwing warning and tab bar icons not rendering

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm working on my Swift app and am receiving some missing tab icons and a warning when the user logs in. I'd like to ask for some advice to solve this if possible.

I have a login view controller, and I have a "home" screen that is a tab view controller. When you click login, I have an asynchronous method occur in the button click event which tries to log you in. If successful, it fires another asynchronous method that retrieves your user data, and then once loaded (takes 1-2 seconds) executes the following commands to take you to the home screen:

```
var vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I do this, it takes me to the home screen (with my tabstrip on the bottom) but two things happen:

1. My tab bar only shows the first (selected icon) but the other 4 are missing until I click on them (then it auto redraws them all). If I wait a while sometimes the icons all just appear simultaneously.
2. It throws a warning:

**Warning: Attempt to present UITabBarController: 0x7f8ec51a1330 on LoginViewController: 0x7f8ec50157c0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

So far, all I've discovered is that if I remove the async call to load the user settings (entirely) from my server then the tab icons appear intact immediately, but the warning is still thrown. Could my async call somehow be screwing up the icons? I'm using task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest so that should be async right?

What about the warning?

Thanks so much!

p.s. I did a bit of searching here and it seems like others are experience this warning in the reverse (moving a user from a tab view controller to a login screen).

Answer (score 0):

Would still love a pair of eyes on this if someone thinks this is wrong, but here is what I ended up doing to solve it:

Instead of

```
var vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I did:

```
var vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vcHome") as UIViewController
var window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
window?.rootViewController! = vc
```

So maybe the problem was the root view controller was still the login controller when I present the new one?

**The only problem now is there is about a 4 second delay before going over to the home screen. Would setting the root view controller be the cause of this?**

Thanks!